# Managing .NET MVC HTTP errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I currently have a site running locally. Before publishing my site, I was customizing the HTTP error codes. I'm purposely throwing a 404 error in my code, and instead of displaying the error page I want, I see HTTP's own error page.
I write this code in my controller that loads the page: `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);`

global.asax :

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            bool isAjaxRequest = Context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";

            if (!isAjaxRequest)
            {
                if (exception is HttpException httpException)
                {
                    int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
                    if (httpCode == 404)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Error/NotFound");
                    }
                    else if (httpCode == 500)
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Error/ServerError");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Error/Error");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Error/Error");
                }
            }
        }
```

Web.Config :

```
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/Error">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/NotFound" />
            <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/ServerError" />
        </customErrors>
```

Error Controller :

```
  public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult NotFound() 
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ServerError()
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? I am not sure I understand what you are asking here. Can you clarify?

Comment: When I return the 404 code I mentioned in the description, it directs me directly to HTTP's own error page, without the customErrors or Application_Error sections working. It should redirect to the "NotFound" page I mentioned in the codes, right?

Comment: You **should not** use `Response.Redirect` for handling server-side errors: it will indicate to browsers/clients that the request _didn't fail_ and the redirect is "normal" - which will break everything (the back-button, bookmarks, etc). To _re-execute_ a request to show an error page use `Server.Transfer` instead. Currently, if a browser requests a non-existant resources, your web-app will return HTTP 3xx + HTTP 200 (caused by the redirect, then the HTTP 200 from `GET /Error/NotFound`, so the browser never sees a real HTTP 404 response - do you see the problem?

Comment: Perhaps this link can help you?

https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-customerrors-element-with-aspnet-explained/